# Dependency Contradiction in code generator

Tags: python, multithreading, oop, code-generation

My current project is to attempt to port the popular card game [Mao](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mao_%28card_game%29) into a LAN game (multiplayer) where the computer will be the 'Grand Master.' It will keep track of the rules, the deck, the players, etc. Mao, however, has no official rule set; instead the players make up the rules. So my rule class thus has very basic properties setup so that code can be generated using a RuleHandler class (whose instance runs in a separate thread) from only a few properties:

- The trigger (Either a card (when it is placed on the pile) or Text/Action)
- Optional conditionals (i.e: if there is not a full deck then...)
- 6 (mostly) basic actions on any of the variables in the game:

  1. Remove the variable (Like deleting  a card or removing a player)

     - `'del({variable})'`
  2. Set a variable to a value (For example, setting the player order (an int) to a negative (which would reverse the order))

     - `'{variable} = {value}'`
  3. 'Replace' two variables (a,b = b,a; such as switching two players' hands or the deck and the pile

     - `'{variable1}, {variable2} = {variable2}, {variable1}'` (really just a fancy `Set` action)
  4. 'New', which makes a new object (such as a new card)

     - `'{list}.append({class}({parametres}))'` (Makes a new object of class using parametres and adds it to the appropriate list (cards to pile or deck, new rule to the RuleHandler, etc.))
  5. Call, which just calls another rule's code

     - `'self.rules.get({rule})rule'` (rules is a dictionary with the key being the rule object that contains all the info and the value being the generated code after `compile`-ing it)
  6. Say, which makes a player say something

     - Not a simple one liner, and oversteps it's class bounds (references player connections and chat)

The last one is the most complicated and the one I am having trouble with. As an example, a common rule in Mao is that if someone puts down a '7' of any suit, they must say 'Have a nice day.' If the next player puts down a '7', then they must say 'Have a very nice day.' The "very's" keep adding on until someone does not put a '7', where they must say 'Thank you very much', where the number of "very's" being the number of "very's" in the last 'Have a very nice day' + 1 while also drawing that number of cards as punishment. While a complicated rule, most of that can easily be achieved through temporary variables and a log of what was the last card placed. However, the code that makes sure the player says the correct phrase is what is stumbling me. The rest of the actions take part behind the scenes and don't require any user input. Waiting for user input is part of the Server code's job, and shouldn't be part of the RuleHandler class.

What do I do to make sure the `Say` action is simple and does not overstep the Single-Responsibility property of Object-Orientated Programming?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you could solve it in a game state way. E.g. a seven is played and 'very' was mentioned once in the say action. Possible next actions are another 7 + very*2 or any other card + very*2. If those two options aren't chosen, the player failed the rule.

Comment: Oh, so the RuleHandler could have a wait method that takes a queue as an argument and will time out after some time if the right phrase is not added in time?

Comment: Why the timeout? Should'n be there always a next player making a turn? I mean timeout in turn based multiplayer always makes sense but isn't that a different issue?

Comment: I am planing this around turn based multiplayer (sorry if I was not clear about that--I'll edit the post), and the rule is in a seperate thread (which I realise was also not said), so the code that keeps track of the current player is always running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to store the phrase in a Queue, with each phrase checked against said Queue each time someone says something. I.E: If someone says 'Dog' and 'Dog' is in the Queue, it removes it, giving the original code in the rule that was waiting on that the flag it needs to continue execution.